# SBT Set javac max heap

Tags: java, scala, sbt, javac

I'm trying to compile some very large Java source files in a Scala/SBT project. How can I set the max heap size for the Java Compiler (javac).

Setting

`javacOptions in Compile ++= Seq("-target", "1.7", "-source", "1.7", "-Xmx1g")`

fails with an invalid argument exception on `-Xmx1g`... Setting `-J-Xmx2g` give similar errors.

Is there a way I can fork `javac`?

Using sbt v 0.13.8

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As you've noticed this seems to be a bug introduced in sbt `0.13.8`, see [#1968](https://github.com/sbt/sbt/issues/1968).

The workaround is to downgrade to `0.13.7` where this doesn't happen.

Comment: Thanks. Yeah. Really is there anyway to force forking of javac?

Comment: well "fork := true" is how you fork, see www.scala-sbt.org/0.13/docs/Forking.html

Comment: Yeah downgrade did, fork didnt

Comment: can you provide detail on what problem you're haivng with 0.13.7? I'm having difficulty reproducing anything

Comment: Yeh so 0.13.7 works. Fork in 0.13.8 doesnt work. I was wanting to know if its possible to force fork javac in 0.13.8...

Comment: Well "fork := true" is how to "force forking" but obviously there's a regression in 0.13.8 that that issue is tracking, which is why I said that the workaround is to downgrade to 0.13.7.